# Multicore ARM how to assign a critical task to one dedicated core

Tags: arm, multicore

Suppose I have a multicore ARM processor (to make it simple assume 2 cores with an unshared cache between the 2 cores). Suppose my system contains a critical task and several non-critical tasks.

Therefore, can I assign the critical task to "core 1" exclusively. And all other to "core 2" exclusively?

If so, what are the best practices from an implementation point of view [assume I use C]? Should I use a library (if so which one) ? An RTOS?

Comment: This is more of a software question, not an EE question.

Comment: That will be a question about your operating system, not about the hardware.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: Ugh - question just came over to stack overflow.  Thanks guys :)  Funny thing is, my answer was basically the same as yours.

Comment: @Sparky256  I have created a new post on StackOverflow as you told me it's the wrong place. I validated the answer given on stackoverflow. Nevertheless, I think that Jeroen3 answer's is useful and should be kept for other users who may have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked with NXP LPC4300 series dual core ARM Cortex M chips.

You do not "assign" tasks as you do on a PC. The way you do this is to compile two separate projects, since both cores operate completely independently, apart from the shared bus.

If you have an multi Cortex A processor you use an operating system to run tasks.
I wouldn't even think about programming these bare metal.